# Blocking outgoing SMS/MMS in android

Tags: android

I have Read Incoming SMS Content and Blocked the same before entering in to the inbox. The code is Given below:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SEND_SMS";
    public static int MSG_TPE=0;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    { 
        String MSG_TYPE=intent.getAction();
            if(MSG_TYPE.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
        {
//          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Received: "+MSG_TYPE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//          toast.show();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) 
        {
            smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }

        // show first message
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"BLOCKED Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
            abortBroadcast();
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Blocking SMS **********************");
            }

        }
        else if(MSG_TYPE.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SEND_SMS"))
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"SMS SENT: "+MSG_TYPE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            abortBroadcast();
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Blocking SMS **********************");
            }

        }
        else
        {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"SIN ELSE: "+MSG_TYPE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            abortBroadcast();
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Blocking SMS **********************");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The code works fine on Incoming SMS. Shows the Sms pdu on Toast and blocks the SMS to enter in to Inbox.
But my problem is that same Code is not working for Outgoing SMS. It doesnt blocks the Outgoing SMS. I have registered BroadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifest as follows.

```
<service  android:name=".MyService"    android:enabled="true"/>
         <receiver android:name="BroadCastReceiver">
                <intent-filter  android:priority="2147483647">
                    <action   android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
    <service  android:name=".MyServiceSentReceived"    android:enabled="true"/>
             <receiver android:name="BroadCastReceiver">
                    <intent-filter  android:priority="2147483645">
                        <action   android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                    </intent-filter>
             </receiver>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"></action>
                <data android:scheme="smsto"></data>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            </intent-filter>

    and Permissions Like:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />  
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Can anyone please help me What is going wrong and why i am not able to block outgoing SMS. Thanks

Comment: [Check my answer here]: (http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/24996424/3884250)! I have explained here to block outgoing and incoming sms.

Answer (score 2):

Your receiver is invoked only, when action `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` is fired. Thus it doesn't react, when SMS is sent.

I am far from being expert, but I think, there is no possibility, to block outgoing messages. The default SMS Application uses `android.telephony.SmsManager`'s method `SendDataMessage()` that doesn't send any broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

I captured the event while sending the sms , i use an observer on  "content://sms/" , i make a query and i get the last sent sms then i delete it : getContentResolver().delete("content://sms/","_id=?",new String[] { message_id});

My problem that this idea work perfectly on Emulator but not on real device.