# Android: Prevent phone from sending SMS

Tags: android, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blocking outgoing SMS/MMS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145823/blocking-outgoing-sms-mms-in-android)

Is it possible in Android to prevent the phone from sending any SMS messages but not disabling the phone altogether?

Comment: you want to disable sending sms from your app?

Comment: Not from my app but from any app.

Comment: have you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145823/blocking-outgoing-sms-mms-in-android)

Comment: Check what? Did you forget a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to blocking `SMSManager` altogether from your phone!
I don't think this would be possible.

- A broadcast sent when SMS is received.
  You can register a handler for that and block the sms from being shown in the inbox.
- But block sending!? Only way out is to keep the phone in airplane mode.

Comment: Came across another posting that seems to indicate that it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595092/how-to-block-outgoing-calls-and-text-sms

Comment: Its for blocking calls, which is possible, but i did not get anything from the thread indicating SMS sending can be blocked..